Diagnosis and Replacement of 2N1101 transistor
I have a circuit board with 3 transistors on it, all of them are 2N1101. I'm trying to diagnose the problem with the board with the diode tester on my multimeter. I found 2 of the transistors have a voltage when connecting positive to either the collector or emitter and negative to base. The voltages are between 0.6v and 1.3v while the third one doesn't show a voltage. My understanding is there shouldn't be voltage from either pin to base.
Questions:

Is my understanding correct and the two transistors are bad?
What is a good replacement for the 2N1101? I'm having trouble finding a datasheet for it and thus a equivalent transistor.


Found a datasheet for the 2N1102, which is almost the same except for a higher voltage rating. Vce is 15V for the 2N1101 according to the abbreviated listing in my GE transistor manual. https://pdf1.alldatasheet.com/datasheet-pdf/view/1073395/NJSEMI/2N1102.html

It's unclear exactly what you did and unclear what the circuit is. Testing in-circuit is tricky. What does "doesn't show a voltage" mean, open or short circuit? Do you have a circuit diagram?

I probably should have may my diagnoses more clear. I put my multimeter in diode testing and attached the positive probe to the emitter and negative to base. This gives 0.68v on Q1 and Q2 and open circuit on Q3. With positive on the collector and negative on base I get 0.8v on Q1, 1.3v on Q2 and open circuit on Q3. All three show 0.6v from positive base to negative collector, positive base to negative emitter gives 0.75v on Q1, and 1.118v on Q2 and Q3.

@ch_7scal It's just three transistors. Why not provide the schematic? It's possible that some good advice could come from that.

Well because it's not my circuit. I don't have a schematic for it.

Your understanding is not correct. With a diode tester a bipolar transistor should show around 0.6 V for silicon, 0.3 V for germanium from both the collector and emitter to the base, depending on which way the probes are connected and if the transistor is NPN or PNP. If you read open across the BE or CE junction with the probes both ways the transistor is bad. This is for an out of circuit transistor, in circuit it’s iffy because other components will affect the readings.
For NPN the junctions should be forward biased and show the normal voltage drop with the positive probe on the base, and the opposite for PNP.

2N1101 is germanium.

@JohnDoty updated.

Thank you both for your expertise and assistance.
